# How to Reduce Nested Dictionaries in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

(In 'pyspark') I have an RDD that contains multiple dictionaries.  Each of these dictionaries, in turn, contain multiple dictionaries.  It looks like this:

```
label1 : {tag1, : count = 2, tag2: count = 3}, {tag2 : count = 3}, {tag3 : count = 1}, ...
label2 : {tag1, : count = 2, tag3: count = 2}, {tag2 : count = 5}, {tag4 : count = 3}, ...
.
.
```

Given this structure, I'd like to be able to "reduce" the dictionaries so the result has the following form:

```
label1 : {tag1 : count = 2}, {tag : count = 6}, {tag3 : count = 1} ...
label2 : {tag1 : count = 2}, {tag2 : count = 5}, {tag3 : count = 2}, {tag4 : count = 3}...
.
.
.
```

I have a feeling this resembles a 'reduce' or 'combine' or 'groupby' but am having difficulty finding the right function.  Can you please point me to which function, in Spark, might accomplish this task?  Thanks!

Comment: In theory, it should not matter what it represents.  Conceptually, I did a GroupByKey() that, according to the Spark documentation, maps a key ('label' in this case) to an "iterable" (a list of dictionaries that map tags to counts).  The result of this call to GroupByKey() is shown above.

Comment: You probably don't want to `GroupByKey` since that places your dictionaries into an iterable. Instead you should group (if you really need to) after you've done your processing within RDDs. Have you looked into performing a `flatten` or a `flatmap` and then organizing it how you want?

Comment: Thanks @EricM.  We have many files where any of the labels, say label3, can appear in any of the files.  I'm new to Spark but my approach was to gather all of the dictionaries that label3 points to across all files and get them into an "iterable".  Then, I'd like to aggregate across that "iterable".  I am taking a stab and saying I "need" to GroupByKey(), but I'm not in any way certain of it.

Comment: That's fine, learning to "think in spark" can take a while. For clarity, you have a large number of text files. The text files can contain a label in a known position. You've identified which files have each label, but you now want to count the amount of files which contain that label? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This should flatten your iterator of dictionaries into one big dictionary:

```
def combine(iter):
    bigDict = dict()
    for littleDict in iter:
        for key, value in littleDict.iteritems():
            bigDict[key] = value
    return bigDict
rdd.map(combine)
```